# How to modify cursor line in Node.js Readline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I have REPL for my language in Node.js and I'm auto indenting lines when user type text by hand and press enter so he have text indented. The problem is that when he copy/paste text that have indents it have double indent.

The problem is that I'm adding indent before the newline happen. So my idea to fix this issue is to some how delete my spaces (rewrite the line) after user press enter and he already have spaces. But I don't know how to do that. Is it possible maybe using some ANSI codes.

my full REPL looks like this:

```
if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
    console.log(banner);
}
var prompt = 'lips> ';
var continuePrompt = '... ';
var terminal = !!process.stdin.isTTY && !(process.env.EMACS || process.env.INSIDE_EMACS);
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    prompt: prompt,
    terminal
});
if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
    rl.prompt();
}
var code = '';
var multiline = false;
var resolve;
var newline;
// we use promise loop to fix issue when copy paste list of S-Expression
var prev_eval = Promise.resolve();
boostrap(interp).then(function() {
    rl.on('line', function(line) {
        code += line.replace(/^\s+/, '') + '\n';
        try {
            if (balanced_parenthesis(code)) {
                rl.pause();
                prev_eval = prev_eval.then(function() {
                    var result = run(code, interp);
                    code = '';
                    return result;
                }).then(function(result) {
                    if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
                        print(result);
                        if (newline) {
                            // readline don't work with not endend lines
                            // it ignore those so we end then ourselfs
                            process.stdout.write("\n");
                            newline = false;
                        }
                        if (multiline) {
                            rl.setPrompt(prompt);
                            multiline = false;
                        }
                        rl.prompt();
                    }
                    rl.resume();
                }).catch(function() {
                    if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
                        if (multiline) {
                            rl.setPrompt(prompt);
                            multiline = false;
                        }
                        rl.prompt();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                multiline = true;
                var ind = indent(code, 2, prompt.length - continuePrompt.length);
                rl.setPrompt(continuePrompt);
                rl.prompt();
                var spaces = new Array(ind + 1).join(' ');
                if (terminal) {
                    rl.write(spaces);
                } else {
                    process.stdout.write(spaces);
                    code += spaces;
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
            code = '';
            rl.prompt();
        }
    });
});
```

I'm using rl.write(spaces); in multiline command after user type his line and I need to check if

I think that I need is to modify the line that have cursor in Node.js Readline.

I've tried:

```
    rl.on('line', function(line) {
        if (line.match(/^\s/)) {
            rl.write(null, { ctrl: true, name: 'u' });
            rl.write((multiline ? continuePrompt : prompt) + line);
        }
        line = line.replace(/^\s+/, '');
        code += line + '\n';
```

and

```
    rl.on('line', function(line) {
        var have_spaces = line.match(/^\s/);
        line = line.replace(/^\s+/, '');
        if (have_spaces) {
            rl.pause();
            process.stdout.write('\x1b[1K\x1b[0K' + line);
            rl.resume();
        }
        code += line + '\n';
```

but both just echo in next line after I press enter, not the line that have cursor in. How to modify line that have cursor? I happy with library that will do that, I was not able to find any that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I've got, to exactly answer the question in title, you can modify the input using keypress event:

```js
rl._writeToOutput = function _writeToOutput(string) {
    rl.output.write(scheme(string));
};
process.stdin.on('keypress', (c, k) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        rl._refreshLine(); // force refresh colors
    }, 0);
});
```

this highlight the line and refresh the line on each keypress to force colors.

And for indent I've solved my issue using this code and ANSI escape codes.

```js
var terminal = !!process.stdin.isTTY && !(process.env.EMACS || process.env.INSIDE_EMACS);

bootstrap(interp).then(function() {
    rl.on('line', function(line) {
        code += line;
        const lines = code.split('\n');
        const cols = process.stdout.columns;
        // fix formatting for previous lines that was echo
        // ReadLine will not handle those
        if (terminal && lines.length > 2) {
            var count = 0;
            // correction when line wrapps in original line
            // that will be overwritten
            lines.map(line => {
                if (line.length > cols) {
                    count += Math.ceil(line.length / cols) - 1;
                }
            });
            var f = new Formatter(code);
            code = f.format();
            const stdout = scheme(code).split('\n').map((line, i) => {
                var prefix;
                if (i === 0) {
                    prefix = unify_prompt(prompt, continuePrompt);
                } else {
                    prefix = unify_prompt(continuePrompt, prompt);
                }
                return '\x1b[K' + prefix + line;
            }).join('\n');
            let num = lines.length + count;
            const format = `\x1b[${num}F${stdout}\n`;
            process.stdout.write(format);
        }
        code += '\n';
        ...
```

There is only one issue with this code when lines are longer then the width of the terminal the updating of lines are broken, and when you copy paste text last line is not indented properly (it have double indent) until you press enter.

Answer (score 0):

In readline module, whenever you press enter, readline clears the current line then emits the line event: [readline.js source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/e3e054d020ee5ef665fc3bededa6c18f3d44e668/lib/readline.js#L705), meaning you can't modify the previous line's output when the line event fires. This sounds disappointing, but we have a workaround:

1. you can try this basic version:

```js
const readline = require('readline')
const input = process.stdin
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: input,
  output: process.stdout,
})

rl.prompt()
input.setEncoding('utf8')

input.on('data', (input) => {
  const REGEXP = /^\s+/
  let haveSpaces = null
  if (input.length > 1) {
    input = input.replace(REGEXP, (match) => {
      if (match) {
        haveSpaces = true
        return ''
      }
    })
    if (haveSpaces) {
      rl.write(null, { ctrl: true, name: 'u' })
      rl.write(input)
    }
  }
})
```

By listening to the input stream's `data` event, you can determine whether the user pasted a string with indentation and then modify the input

2. or make it more easy and interactive with [repll](https://github.com/beetcb/repll):

```js
const { replLive, onInput } = require('repll')
const repll = replLive(['repll› '], 'A meaningful placeholder')

onInput((input) => {
  const REGEXP = /^\s+/
  let haveSpaces = null
  if (input.length > 1) {
    input = input.replace(REGEXP, (match) => {
      if (match) {
        haveSpaces = true
        return ''
      }
    })
    if (haveSpaces) {
      repll.write(null, { ctrl: true, name: 'u' })
      repll.write(input)
      repll.refresh('Your pasted text have indents! We already fixed that')
    }
  }
})
```

I have a module([repll](https://github.com/beetcb/repll)) that handles these scenario with livly output and placeholder and many other interactive features.

3. for syntax heightlight, see this demo on [`repl.it`](https://repl.it/talk/share/repll-heightlight/116960)(cause i do not want this answer gets too long to read).Remember to run it inside `shell` (not `console`)

Comment: Thanks, your first solution is almost working, the problem it's working only when I copy paste text that don't have blank newline at the end. About your module does it have history? In my code I've copied code from Node.js to have history written to file.

Comment: Unfortunately your library don't work at all, onInput is not executed and I'm not able to paste code that have syntax highlighitng.

Comment: It seems that your first solution also don't work, I don't get prompt after I've added `input.on('data', ` When using this it block user input and don't even get my REPL to run.

Comment: have blank newline at the end(`\r\n` or `\n`) acts similar to enter, readline will force terminal to create a new line. As for the repll issue,`onInput` works fine based on my testing(paste syntax highlighitng text works), make sure you doing it right.
If there's still a problem, you can report a issue with your `code`

Comment: Try the third solution，it solves: 
> it's working only when I copy paste text that don't have blank newline at the end

Comment: That problem was my mistake both solution don't work at all, I've put the code in wrong place it's not executing, and in your library onInput is never triggered. I can create simple POC for your library to show you that your library don't work at all.

Comment: Did you even tested to make the text for instance red and add `...` before each line with your library? I've tried to add syntax highlight and color is white and not indented so your onInput is never executed.

Comment: And adding `input.on('data', (input) => {` disable readline.

Comment: > And adding input.on('data', (input) => { disable readline.

To fix this, make sure you call `rl.prompt()` on every new line in `readline` module
:
rl.on('line', (input) => {
  rl.prompt()
})

Comment: I've updated my answes with syntax heightlight, please see solution 3 (BTW, you can give `onAny` a shot if `onInput` didn't work for you)

Comment: It don't work on GNU Linux with bash and I don't have any colors, also clear screen is really annoying so your library is of no use to me.

Comment: onAny also don't work at all, the callback is never executed the same as onInput.

Comment: Sorry to here that, If that's the case, readline won't work for you either, my module is based on it( `onAny` is listening on readline input stream's 'data' evet) , does `input.on('keypress')` works?

Comment: My repl works fine I use keypress but simple example using your solutions or you library don't work at all. Maybe you should test on different OSes and write that it's only for Windows or MacOS. Since I've added this question I have almost working REPL with everything I wanted, maybe I should add my own answer, since mine is actually working. One issue that is missing is that if there are no newline at the end the line is not indented because the line is event is not triggered. You can check how my REPL works using `npx @jcubic/lips@beta`

Comment: Note that my REPL is a lot bigger then your whole library.

Comment: Yeah, lips works. I actually always test mine on GUN Linux (arch) with konsole as the terminal and `repl.it` shell and my own server, they all works. Cloud you bother to create a issue on github to reproduce your problem? That would be helpful ☺️, THANKS

Comment: It seems that onInput is executed on single character, one by one. that's why your example don't work, because the `if` always return `false`.

Comment: Nope! When you paste something long, `input.lenght` will be greater than 1, under the hood, `onAny` callback will be triggered whenever stdin changes

Comment: It seems that your llibrary have two API here in this answer you use argument to onInput that is single character and on GitHub you use `repll.input` that is whole string.